# How to match sequential string in text using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am using python's `re` module to match sequential string in text, for example:
`s = 'habcabcabcj'`, I try the following code:

```
import re
re.findall(r'(abc)+', s)
```

And the result is: `["abc"]`

If I want the match result to be `["abcabcabc"]`, how can I do this?

Comment: You haven't asked, but the reason *why*  you got `"abc"` as a result is because `re.findall()` behaves differently when [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) are present in the regex. Without them, a list of all the complete matches will be returned. With them, only the contents of the capturing group(s) will be returned (as a list of tuples if there's more than one). And a repeated capturing group overwrites its contents with every repetition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a non-capturing group [`(?:...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'habcabcabcj'
>>> re.findall(r'(?:abc)+', s)
['abcabcabc']
>>>
```